# Magento2: How to center box with price, product name etc

Tags: magento2, template, css

I try to center box with product details:
[image]

So, in `list.phtml` I found code responsible for this box.

```
<div class="product details product-item-details">
                        <hr />
                            <h5 class="product name product-item-name">
                                                <?php 
                            $optionText = '';
                            $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('mgs_brand');
                            if ($attr->usesSource()) {
                               $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_product->getMgsBrand());
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?php if($optionText){ ?>
                            <div class="brand-name"><?php echo $optionText ?></div>
                        <?php } ?>
                            </h5>

                                                <a class="product-item-link" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                                </a>

                            <?php if(!$themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/review')): ?>
                                <?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType,true); ?>
                            <?php endif ?>

                            <?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>

                            <?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>
                            <?php if ($themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/disable_add_to_cart') == 0 && $themeHelper->getStoreConfig('mpanel/catalog/disable_hover_effect') == 1): ?>
                                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <div>
                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                        <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/add', ['uenc'=>$postParams['data']['uenc'], 'product'=>$postParams['data']['product']]); ?>" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="uenc" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['uenc']; ?>">
                                            <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey() ?>" />
                                            <button class="action tocart btn-cart hover_effect" type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
                                                <span class="icon pe-7s-shopbag"></span>
                                                <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif ?>
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </div>
```

In CSS file in section:

```
// Products Grid
```

I see code:

```
.product-item-details {
    padding-top: 11px;
    .product-item-name {
        margin-bottom: 6px;
        line-height: 1.1;
        a {
            color: #222;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 500;
            &:hover {
                color: @base-color;
            }
        }
    }
    .product-reviews-summary, .product.description {
        margin-top: 8px;
    }
}
```

after `.product-item-details {` I add code: `float: left;`

After update file I try delete generated folder and deploy system again. No result.

Any solution?

Comment: Can you provide the URL ?

Comment: You can check in Gerris.pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.products .product.name, .products .rating-result, .products a.product-item-link, .products .price-box {
    display: table;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.products .product-items .product-item-info .rewards__product-points .price {
    color: #878787 !important;
    left: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

Update:

[image]

Comment: I add to custom style in backend: https://prnt.sc/mah2ms but after refresh cache still I not see any changed in frontend

Comment: The properties are not present in the website, please try to add them instead in `app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Theme/web/css/theme.css` then deploy the static content and clean cache

Comment: Also now I'm try to add this code to end of file theme.css and try deploy but still no result :(

Comment: I don't know why  but it should work, look my update

Comment: I accept your answear because you have right and should be all work. I try delete static frontend because I think there are no visible css changes on the frontend

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without knowing what theme you have, or seeing the rest of the CSS and surrounding HTML, but depending on what you want you could either add
 `text-align: center;` to `.product-item-details` to center the text, or set a limited size on the `.product-item-details` container (maybe a `width: 60%`) and `margin: 0 auto;` to center the box with the left-aligned content still in it.

Answer (score 0):

.brand-name {
float : right;
}